# dropbox get network connection status

Tags: networking, dropbox, status

How can I get dropbox connection status？Even if I turn off the network

```
DbxDatastore.getSyncStatus().isDownloading
```

is return ture，and because dropbox can't use in some places(tianchao)，so Even if the network is connected，dropbox  is still not properly connected . help me

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting more questions.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202034019-android-dropbox-DbxDatastore-synchronous-interrupts-get-connection-status ]